# Convert HTML select/optgroup to Flex

Tags: html, flex3

New to Flex, what is the nearest equivalent to the following HTML markup in Flex?

```
<select size="9">
    <optgroup label="Group 1">
        <option>Value 1</option>
        <option>Value 2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 2">
        <option>Value 5</option>
        <option>Value 6</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 3">
        <option>Value 8</option>
        <option>Value 9</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is none that maps directly. You could try this -- [a sample implementation](http://www.phusor.com/flex/optgroup_demo/srcview/index.html) (using `Combobox`) or to roll your own using either `Combobox` or [`RadioButtonGroup`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/RadioButtonGroup.html).